# Autodesk Forge Data Management API Get Top Folders request now returns 404 Not Found consistently today, but was working last week

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-bim360

We are using Autodesk Forge Data Management and BIM 360 APIs to create new BIM 360 projects.  Last week everything was working fine. Now, after creating and activating the new project, the Get Top Folders request is consistently returning 404 Not Found all morning and early afternoon.  Is there a partial outage?  Change to the API that's not documented yet? Something else?

The documentation for my perhaps-broken request is [here](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/data/v2/reference/http/hubs-hub_id-projects-project_id-topFolders-GET/).

I am aware that both the hub id and the project id should have a "b." prefix to the guid, and my request has this.

Re. Authorization: I have been using the same authentication on previous requests literally milliseconds prior, so my authentication token should be fine.

Re. the request header marked as optional in the documentation 'x-user-id', I am not sending one since it is optional.

As a side note, I am submitting all of my requests from a C# application using RestSharp.

Thanks in advance for any assistance!

EDIT

The error message returned is:
"status":"404",
"code":"ProjectNotExistException",
"title":"Error Project Operations.",
"detail":"Project with id "(guid redacted)" does not exist in database"}

When logged in to the latest project that was created, approximately an hour later, it looks like document management is having trouble activating.  Perhaps that's all?

[image: Screen shot showing a spinning spinner next to 'Activing...' below 'Document Management' in the Project Admin page.]

EDIT 2

Yes, that appears to be the problem.  Approximately 25 minutes later the Document Management Activation completed, and I was able to finish my full process including getting the top folders and a few subsequent Forge requests.

BUT WHY DOES IT TAKE AN HOUR TO ACTIVATE WHEN IT TOOK MERE SECONDS LAST WEEK?

Comment: Hi, we are investigating the issue, still on going with the engineering team. will circle back when we get a solution thanks for your patience.

Comment: Thank you for the update Jaime.

Comment: @JaimeRosales I have the same error. Getting the topfolders work for me. Creating a new folder in the top folder does not work for me, then I get the same message. Document Management service is active (green) in my project admin > services.

Answer (score 0):

I contacted the Forge team last Friday and they are aware of this issue. It seems to be a problem in the queue for doc management service activation. Also, noticed it is on and off. Usually, improves very early in the morning. I have not tried at night.

In order to minimize the impact on the users creating projects, we decided to send out notifications to Hub Admins when the app cannot get the Top Folders. This is an indication that the doc management service is taking longer that expected to activate. Then, we know that we need to void/archive that project(if user does not want to wait 1-4 hours) and create a new one through the BIM 360 UI (The problem seems to be only when using the API). Finally, we route the original user to continue where they left in the process.

It is not a pretty solution, but that alert us when it fails. I hope Forge can fix the problem soon.

Comment: Thanks! Good to know that they are aware of the problem.  We've found a workaround too.  It's a bummer since it's tough to test anything in our application that comes after this when it's so unreliable. But, we forge ahead, LOL.